Intermittent networking issues could be related to dns on ubuntu 24.04 iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
Im running ubuntu 24.04. Its been working fine but as of yesterday i rebooted and started having strange "internet" issues.
I can connect to the wifi but im having issues that come ago some related to resolving dns.

I went to wifi -> ipv4 -> dns -> disable automatic -> added 8.8.8.8. This worked for a little but was flakey, sometimes i could connect to google and youtube and other google related services but no other services like github.

Ultiamtely decided to reset the above ^ and after a couple of restarts i was able to connect to all websites. However it would not last very long as it kept cutting out and pages were unable to be loaded again.


i can see a few messages in sudo dmesg I'm hoping someone could help me understand this a little more.
[  580.788642] net_ratelimit: 3 callbacks suppressed
[  580.788647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  580.849658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  583.966644] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  584.224223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  584.470636] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  584.721781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  584.973722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  584.976564] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  585.225837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  585.226992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  642.140662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  654.602276] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255344.232:264): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=10004 comm="Renderer" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  654.847302] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255344.477:265): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=10004 comm="Renderer" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  656.009123] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255345.639:266): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=10004 comm="Renderer" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  659.009079] wlo1: disconnect from AP 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 for new auth to 54:83:3a:76:45:76
[  659.043567] wlo1: authenticate with 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (local address=e8:c8:29:23:fb:27)
[  659.044647] wlo1: send auth to 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (try 1/3)
[  659.077617] wlo1: authenticated
[  659.078560] wlo1: associate with 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (try 1/3)
[  659.086130] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (capab=0x1911 status=30 aid=0)
[  659.086158] wlo1: 54:83:3a:76:45:76 rejected association temporarily; comeback duration 262144 TU (268435 ms)
[  664.078392] wlo1: aborting association with 54:83:3a:76:45:76 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  664.363763] wlo1: authenticate with 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (local address=e8:c8:29:23:fb:27)
[  664.364963] wlo1: send auth to 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (try 1/3)
[  664.396978] wlo1: authenticated
[  664.397570] wlo1: associate with 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (try 1/3)
[  664.398998] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=4)
[  664.407353] wlo1: associated
[  664.466275] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 19 (20 - 1) dBm as advertised by 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51
[  704.156142] wlo1: disconnect from AP 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 for new auth to 54:83:3a:76:45:76
[  704.191737] wlo1: authenticate with 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (local address=e8:c8:29:23:fb:27)
[  704.192838] wlo1: send auth to 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (try 1/3)
[  704.224480] wlo1: authenticated
[  704.225389] wlo1: associate with 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (try 1/3)
[  704.231231] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from 54:83:3a:76:45:76 (capab=0x1911 status=0 aid=18)
[  704.237917] wlo1: associated
[  704.331524] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 54:83:3a:76:45:76
[  706.151946] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  707.176027] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  708.198429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  709.221414] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  710.246725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  711.269556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  712.321057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  713.318752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  714.341043] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  715.370140] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  716.393380] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  717.420511] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  718.443643] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  719.464464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  720.488592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  721.088045] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  721.515867] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  722.087653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  722.546797] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  723.111822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  723.562587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  724.131568] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  724.586865] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  725.177647] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  725.610498] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  726.183697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  726.633464] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  727.659651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  728.192165] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  728.229212] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  728.681085] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  729.704412] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  730.729055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  731.757103] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  732.264617] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  732.779235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  733.801556] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  734.835676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  735.907327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  736.993932] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  737.895418] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  738.919596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  739.946015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  740.516304] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  740.962551] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  767.679921] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.310:267): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=13963 comm="snap-confine" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  767.679939] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.310:268): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=13963 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
[  767.687253] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.317:269): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap-update-ns.firefox" name="/proc/13982/maps" pid=13982 comm="5" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  767.910253] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.540:270): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  767.912297] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.543:271): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  767.912303] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.543:272): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  767.912483] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.543:273): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  767.912586] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.543:274): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:0" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  767.916287] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.547:275): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:255" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  767.916389] audit: type=1400 audit(1720255457.547:276): apparmor="DENIED" operation="symlink" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/dev/char/195:254" pid=14031 comm="glxtest" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[  838.499917] wlo1: disconnect from AP 54:83:3a:76:45:76 for new auth to 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51
[  838.531145] wlo1: authenticate with 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (local address=e8:c8:29:23:fb:27)
[  838.531869] wlo1: send auth to 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (try 1/3)
[  838.562246] wlo1: authenticated
[  838.562851] wlo1: associate with 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (try 1/3)
[  838.564275] wlo1: RX ReassocResp from 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 (capab=0x1011 status=0 aid=4)
[  838.571265] wlo1: associated
[  838.650976] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 19 (20 - 1) dBm as advertised by 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51
[  839.045189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[  839.201426] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b

sudo lshw -C networl
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Raptor Lake-S PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 11
       serial: e8:c8:29:23:fb:27
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-36-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-gf-a0-86.uc latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:18 memory:625c144000-625c147fff


@amar Ive only connected with the single wifi network ap we have

@amar sorry i dont understand you. Ive not selected a specific band to connect to. If you could provide me with more information on how to investigate what you are saying i'd be happy to check and report back.

UPDATE: THIS DID NOT WORK: After rebooting my laptop. Wifi still disocnnecting with the Unhandled alg error. (i checked the wifi did connect with ipv4) so the below did not resolve my issue.
I may have resolved the issue, i'm going to leave this as "a" answer here, but won't mark it as resolved until ive been able to test it for a few days.
I setup terminals to monitor both sudo dmesg -w -T & journalctl -f -b -u NetworkManager. Aswell as both ping 8.8.8.8 and ping google.com

When i was connected to my parents WIFI i noticed;

Either pings would ocasionally fail and was expericing a lot of packet loss.  I thought it was itneresting where there were times when (google.com) was wroking but the IP address came back as network not found.
in dmesg it was showing that the conection was disconnecting aswell as showing iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
in journalctl Jul 06 12:37:18 khan NetworkManager[1314]:   [1720265838.3135] policy: set '' (wlo1) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
I tested for about an hour.

i decided to try my phone's hotspot and connected. The connection was stable. Pings were not dropping and no packet loss again for 1 hour.

in dmesg no iwlwifi logs
in journalctl  policy: set 'K HOTSPOT' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

In the case of my home wifi (the unstable connection) it was defaulting to ipv6, with my hotspot it was defaulting to ipv4.
I've modified wifi to ignore ipv6
nmcli connection modify <redacted> ipv6.method "ignore"

Then i rebooted the connection with nmcli connection down <redacted> and nmcli connection up <redacted>
So far it looks promising im no longer receiving iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
Curious to understand why my home wifi is defaulting to ipv6 and why that would cause instability.

704.156142] wlo1: disconnect from AP 4c:1b:86:8d:44:51 for new auth to 54:83:3a:76:45:76 There is 3 of these in your dmesg. try to find out why.
